# Unable to click links saved in List after the first link is clicked through selenium webdriver

Tags: list, selenium, hyperlink, automation, webdriver

I am trying to click all the product links one by one that are saved in a List in this [website](https://www.barneys.com/category/women/shoes/boots/N-po186i). The first link is getting clicked however, when the page is navigated back to click the second link, I am getting error "StaleReferenceException". I am struck at line - elementToBeClicked.click(); I have searched on internet the methods to resolve this type of error but was not successfull. Please help me out. Here is my code:

```
 WebElement prodList = util.getdriver().findElement(By.id("atg_store_prodList"));
                                // Finding all links and saving in a list
                                List<WebElement> alllinks = prodList.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='product-name']/a"));
                                System.out.println(alllinks);

                                for (int i = 0; i < alllinks.size(); i++) {
                                   alllinks = prodList.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='product-name']/a"));
                                    System.out.println(alllinks.get(i));
                                    WebElement elementToBeClicked = alllinks.get(i);


                                       Thread.sleep(5000);
                                    elementToBeClicked.click();


                                    util.clickbyXpath(Constants.BOOTSIZE);
                                    Thread.sleep(5000);



                               util.getdriver().findElement(By.id("atg_behavior_addItemToCart")).click();

                                        if (util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]"))
                                                .isDisplayed()) {
                                            util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Continue Shopping')]"))
                                                    .click();
                                            util.getdriver().navigate().back();
                                        }

                                        else {

                                            util.getdriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Checkout']")).click();
                                            Select selectCountry = new Select(

                                }
                            }
```

Comment: I couldn't run your code to check the error. However you can check the following [link](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) to see whether you are running into any of these, reasons which are resulting in the "StaleReferenceException" error.

Answer (score 0):

when you click the link, it triggers navigation and you are taken to a new page.  Once new navigation occurs, all the old elements in the DOM become stale and are no longer usable (you are no longer on that page).  You must navigate back to the original page again and reload it to get a new DOM with new elements.

TLDR: triggering navigation refreshes the DOM and elements can no longer be accessed from the old DOM.  That's the way selenium works.

Comment: So how can I click all links,because they are on the same webpage, I am navigating to the previous page, still not able to get the links. I even tried refrshing the page from my end, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working at my end :

```
driver.get("https://www.barneys.com/category/women/shoes/boots/N-po186i");
Thread.sleep(5000);

for(int i=0 ; i<100; i++) {
     int attempts = 0;

    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
        List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-name']/a"));
            alllinks.get(i).click();
            break;
        } 

        catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    // do your operation such as getting the detail of product or anything   
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.navigate().back();
    driver.navigate().refresh();
}
```